# image sizes for Android

Tags: android, image, screen

I want to set specific images for as many screens as possible.
So I created 4 files:

```
res/drawable-ldpi/myfile.png which has 240x360
res/drawable-mdpi/myfile.png which has 320x480
res/drawable-hdpi/myfile.png which has 480x720
res/drawable-xhdpi/myfile.png which has 640x960
```

I have, however, also other images with the other orientations and ratio (resulutions like 768x1024, 1024x768, 1242x2208, 1536x2048 etc). Where should I place them so that the devices with the corresponding screen sizes could use them?

Comment: _What can I do with them?_ -- Well, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: If a device has screen, say, 1242x2208, I want it to use the file with the appropriate resolution

Comment: Rewrite your Question to better explain what you need.

Comment: Why you want to put so many images? Are you targeting tablets also ?

Comment: Yes. The customer sent me a lot of files for different devices/screens asking to use all of them

Answer (score 0):

use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) **9patch** image generator

you have to get xxhdpi and xxxhdpi image use this image for larger screen size

Answer (score 0):

You can add drawables for higher resolution sreens:

> res/drawable-xxhdpi/myfile.png       // Resolution: 960x1440
>
> res/drawable-xxxhdpi/myfile.png      // Resolution: 1280x1920